# Different pv results for median test in R and python

Tags: python, r, scipy, statistics, median

I have a list of 37 values (not normally distributed). I want to know if one or more values among the values are **significantly different** (greater or smaller) than all the others.

For example, if my list of values looks like this:

X = [-0.81,-0.77,-0.63,-0.62,-0.59,-0.42,-0.42,-0.37,-0.34,-0.32,-0.25,-0.15,-0.15,-0.15,-0.14,-0.14,-0.11,-0.07,-0.03,-0.009,0.018,0.031,0.122,0.21,0.27, 0.28, 0.29, 0.35, 0.38, 0.38, 0.412, 0.42,0.51, 0.72, 1.14, 1.477, 7.23]

I would like to test whether the last value of 7.23 is significantly higher than the others.

I found that **"Mood's Median Test"** may be useful for that. I made the one sample as the whole list except 7.23 (z), and the second sample (y) as 7.23.

When I use `scipy` in **Python**: 
`scipy.stats.median_test(z, y)`
(by: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.median_test.html), I get **P-Value= 0.98**. When I use **R** (UsingR package) (`simple.median_test(z, y)`) I get **P-Value < 0.0001**.
(Documentation for R: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/UsingR/versions/2.0-5/topics/simple.median.test)

Why are those differences in results? Do I use the right statistic test?

I've also read that there is "one sample median test" that suppose to work but I can't find the command for that.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Maybe this question is more appropriate for https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You should mention what R package you found `simple.median_test` in since it's not in base. Also mention what the documentation of it say. If, for example, you used `UsingR::simple.median.test`, its docs make no mention of "Mood's median test", but it does say it returns a p-value. Your Python doc says it returns a test statistic and a p-value (and more). A test Chi Sq test statistic of 0.98 corresponds to a very low p-value, < .0001. Are you sure you're looking at the right python output?

Comment: If you look at the doc of the python function. It is 1) calculating the global median: `med=median(c(z,y))`, 2) constructing a contingency table of how many values in z and y fall below vs above med: `m=matrix(c(sum(z>med),sum(z<=med),sum(y>med),sum(y<=med)),2,2)`. 3) performing a chi square test on this table: `chisq.test(m)`. If you do that in R, you get a p-value of 0.9781. Not sure what the `simple.median.test` function is doing though..

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. 
1. I have posted it on stats.stackexchange.com but got no answers. 2. I edited the question and add the R package and documentation. 3. If I get it right, you are saying that the tests I've used in Python and R are not the same? What should I use? I'm very confused.... Thank you again...

Comment: Please don't crosspost.